# Single page site, pageview not sending panel name

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm looking for some help troubleshooting some page view tracking. While I understand this conceptually, I need help with the coding.

I'm using this jquery script: http://dynamical.biz/blog/technical-analytics/better-approach-to-tracking-single-page-sites-google-analytics-73.html

I want to track when a visitor views a "floor plan" panel on a page. The script is firing a page view as some of the floor plans scroll into position, which I can see with GA Debug. There are two things I need help with.

I don't see is the data-vp-name="/panelname" attribute being sent with the page view.

I see this at the top of each pageview in the GA Debug console. I assume the "undefined" is part of the problem.

```
Running command: ga("send", "pageview", undefined)
```

Also the pageviews do not fire on some of the panels further down the page.

This is the page in question. http://theheightslindensquare.com/floor-plans.html

This is for mobile only, so you need to change the browser to less than 600px to see what's happening.

Any help you might provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple mistake in your code, you are using the attribute `data-vp-name` and the script asks for `data-vpn-name`. Note the missing 'n' in 'vpn'.

I believe that a virtual pageview with no pageview path attribute makes no sense, and that is why GA is not tracking it. **EDIT:** The virtual pageview will use the current location if undefined, as per noted by @brian-K

Hope this is your fix.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake in the attribute name. . . *slaps forehead*

Comment: I also adjusted the distance and timing variables just a bit. Now the only thing left is the last panel is not reporting.

Answer (score 1):

The correction to the data-vp-name will show which panels are being tracked as Virtual Pageviews and show the underlying problem more clearly (see below)

However,

```
ga('send', 'pageview' [, virtualPageView|undefined]);
```

will always send a pageview. The undefined value merely causes GA to use 
`document.location.pathname + document.location.search` as the page name.

Also the method for each panel being reported is generic - it applies to all panels equally so if one reports so will the others under the same conditions.

However, the underlying problem is that their relative positions and the sensitivity of settings may affect each differently.

Tweaking the settings may improve how the panels are reported.
Removing the delay (in startInterval(), change the interval from 1000 to 0)
may also make this kind of testing easier.

A challenge is that one can expect the floor plans lower on the page will get fewer views so this needs to be tested thoroughly if you are to trust your data.

Let us know how that goes ...

Comment: You are right on the 'undefined' pageview! Thanks for pointing out!